# Migration from Webpack 1 to 2 Errors - Angular (4.1.3) application

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

I'm trying to migrate my angular application from Webpack 1 to 2. After following the changes from [here](http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2016/10/moving-to-webpack-2/) and [here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/migrating/). And now I'm getting the following error with metadata:

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a 

configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'metadata'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           metadata: ...
         }
       })
     ]
```

But i'm not sure which webpack config file it is pointing to, since I have one for different environments.

In webpack.common.js:

```
const METADATA = {
   title:
   baseUrl: 
}
module.exports = {
   metadata: METADATA,
   ...
}
```

In other webpack files (for dev, local, production, test), I define `const METADATA` and inside `module.exports`, I have

```
webpackMerge(commonConfig, {
   metadata: METADATA, 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the error message refers to config that is passed to webpack. I guess you're using webpackMerge since you have a common config. so basically it would refer to all of your configuration files, since metadata is not a allowed configuration property.
[Here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/) you find an fully fledged configuration. the error message should disappear when you remove the metadata property from your configrations.

If you want to configure stuff like the title or baseUrl within your webpack configuration, you can use the HtmlWebpackPlugin like it is used in [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L305).

Comment: I followed the second link you provided (HtmlWebpackPlugin) worked. But I'm getting `commonConfig` is not a function. Is `module.exports` supposed to be a function?

Comment: it is not supposed to be an function, but i can be a function. it is what you get when you require the file. In the repo its made as a function so that you can pass in options as you can see in line 43.

Comment: I'm now seeing errors related to bootstrap-loader. Not sure why because I have not explicitly used it anywhere in the config files